# No printers are installed in server system

Tags: c#, asp.net

Print is not working in server system. Its showing error message.

> System.Drawing.Printing.InvalidPrinterException: No printers are installed in server system.

```
public void print()
{
    SC.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from converstion where status='A'", SC);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
    da.SelectCommand = cmd;
    DataTable datatable = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(datatable);
    ReportDocument crreport = new ReportDocument();
    crreport.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Conversion.rpt"));       crreport.SetDataSource(datatable);
    crreport.PrintToPrinter(1, false, 0, 0);
    SC.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have to install printer drivers on your server.

Comment: printer driver is installed but same error is showing

Answer (score 0):

I also have received this error because the user account does not have access to printers.